# Simple Message Poster for Friendfeed

Tags: c#, .net, friendfeed

I am trying to integrate a function into an application that posts a message to friendfeed using the C# API. Being a total novice I cannot work out how to make the connection and then publish a message to it.

Can anyone help with this?

I have the HTTP Basic Auth working fine, just not the function to post to my friendfeed account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was using the API docs and had created the HTTP Auth object, but when I trying to get the Friendfeed.FriendfeedClient() to work, it kept coming back with a 405 error. Well long story short, my app was working all along, but due to the error I was seeing I thought it wasn't.

The error itself was due to essentially trying to Auth the HTTP Auth object to the wrong URL.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the [FriendFeed documentation](http://code.google.com/p/friendfeed-api/wiki/ApiDocumentation) spells it out for you. Scroll down to the section titled "Publishing To FriendFeed".

Comment: @DOK - Thanks for your response. I have been working through the API docs, but being a useless programmer it does not seem to want to work for me. I am sure to a real developer it is as plain as day. Thanks anyway.